# Can we set the default attribute value globally of a ScriptManager control in an asp.net 3.5 website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, scriptmanager

Want to set the default value of the attribute of all the `ScriptManager` control.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Keep the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI` to "`false`" for all the `ScriptManager` control.

Comment: You could, at least in my theory, create a class of your own that inherits from `ScriptManager` and set the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI` and use the derived class instead of the oridnary `ScriptManager` in all your pages. I'm not sure that you should though. It breaks the priciple of least astonishment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment.

Comment: Put it in the Master page? one ScriptManager to rule them all?

Comment: My opinion about asp.net-3.5 is that you should try to port your project to newer technologies as asp.net-3.5 is some ten years old and quite dead. I find aspnetcore backend and angular for front end much more modern and nice to work with.

Comment: @gsharp: Yes if it is possible to put the `ScriptManager` in the master page, that would probably be a better idea.